# Jest Unit testing module export error in browser console

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I am trying to use Jest to test my JS code, but why do I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined` in the browser console?

Example:
**app.js**

```
const funct = (a,b) => {
    let sum  = a + b;
    return sum;
}

module.exports = funct;
```

**app.test.js**

```
const funct = require('./app.js')

test('funct func', () => {
    expect(funct(1, 2)).toBe(3);
})
```

The test passes, but I get the module exports error in the browser console?

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `module.exports` like this. In this way, it will not be a problem for both the test and the browser.

```
var module = module || {};
module.exports = funct;
```

Comment: So your adding the module into a variable and declaring as a module or object?

Comment: if `module` is defined use it, if undefined, use an empty object. this will prevent errors. I always use in this way.